# What is the max speed of triggering the flash of iPhone?

Tags: iphone

What is the maximum speed on which I can turn on and off the flash of the iPhone 5?

Comment: Takes me less than a second… I'm not really sure I understand the point of the question. It it a competition? ;-)

Comment: Sounds like he wants to give someone a seizure! :p

Comment: if I speak programmatically then I am asking
// on flash
wait(/*for some time*/)
// off flash
wait(/*for some time*/)

what will be the minimum wait?
If I on and off it through some code then what would be the maximum speed on which I can do that.

Comment: Would love to know the answer to this!